# /review page - "get 30 more" link goes to homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed

When using the **/review** page on **stackoverflow.com** I've noticed that the link at the bottom of the page, **"get [30 more](https://stackoverflow.com/)"** goes to the homepage.

I expect that this should point back to the /review page so I can get 30 more to review.

Its not a big problem as a refresh sorts it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are right - it incorrectly uses `<a href="">30 more</a>` which varies between browsers; on some (chrome, for example) it is interpreted as "current", and on others (IE, for example) it is interpreted as "root".

Fixing. Out of curiosity, I'd love to know whether either is *demonstrably* the correct behaviour (html standards), or whether this is undefined (in which case either is broadly legitimate).

Comment: I think that empty `href` is not valid, or at least not good practice.. I've always used `#` for empty links and saw others using stuff like `href="javascript:void(0);"` but personally dislike it. Edit: here is [recent discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637969/is-an-empty-href-valid) about it. :)

Comment: So in fact, neither is correct then: "As Stated in RFC 2396: A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the current document." ;p

Comment: Actually, Chrome and Firefox are correct while IE is wrong. HTML4 explicitly links to RFC 1808 which describes the process of resolving relative URLs: "If the embedded URL is entirely empty, it inherits the entire base URL (i.e., is set equal to the base URL) and we are done." By default, the base URL is the URL of the current document.

Comment: Well, it's more of "what is better approach" than "what is valid".. :)

Comment: Not that it matters... at the next deploy the url will be explicit

Comment: Didn't realise that the different browsers handled the empty href in different ways. Good to know.

Comment: Consulting the RFC is a lot of work; it's so much easier to just assume IE is wrong

Comment: So the lesson here... is that IE users don't review, or at least aren't dedicated when they do?

Comment: @Popular Demand I spotted the bug whilst reviewing using IE :P

Comment: @ghost, right, but the `/review` page has existed _since 2010_!